# libXaw can't find Bitmaps from /usr/include/X11/bitmaps

Tags: debian, x11, x-resources

When launching Xaw applications, some of them report

```
Warning: Cannot convert string "<somename>" to type Pixmap
```

One such name is `xlogo11`; these names are bitmap files, found in `/usr/include/X11/bitmaps` but the applications simply cannot find the bitmap.

Changing bitmap's name in the Xresources to have the full path causes the bitmaps to display correctly, but this is quite a bad solution, as I would have to edit each app's app-resources file individually.

---

I did some research and found the [Xorg Xaw widgets list](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/libXaw/widgets.pdf), and in section "2.5.3. Bitmap Conversion", it talks about a resource called `bitmapFilePath`, and it says

> When using POSIX the default directory is /usr/include/X11/bitmaps.

This seems to not be working. I'm not sure how libXaw checks if you're using POSIX.

For note, my system is Debian 12 (bookworm) x86_64 with CDE, and I have the xbitmaps package installed.

Comment: Wow, Xaw... That's a name I haven't heard in the last twenty years. Retro! Is the file finding actually handled by libXaw or by the underlying libXt?

Comment: "CDE" sounds like a [non-Debian package](https://www.google.com/search?q=debian+cde&oq=Debian+CDE&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqBwgAEAAYgAQyBwgAEAAYgAQyCAgBEAAYFhgeMggIAhAAGBYYHjIICAMQABgWGB4yDQgEEAAYhgMYgAQYigUyDQgFEAAYhgMYgAQYigUyDQgGEAAYhgMYgAQYigUyDQgHEAAYhgMYgAQYigUyBggIEEUYQNIBCTUxMTlqMGoxNagCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), which may have compiled-in resource defaults using `/usr/X11R6` as a prefix.

Comment: In most distros, default paths in some packages are changed from the default values given upstream. It is likely the path that you've found in the documentation is changed by whoever made the package for the used libraries. It is also possible that there is a separate package containing just the resources, such as the mentioned bitmap. You can always run `find / -name xlogo11` to check if the file is present in the filesystem at all. Debian (unless "testing" or "unstable") is generally not good for this kind of tinkering or programming (with the latest libraries) in general.

Comment: (continued from my previous comment:) If you find the files in different location, you can always create symbolic links to the files in the expected location with ln(1).